# Jquery Click on Image

Tags: jquery

I have a div that has an image. When I click on the image, I like to convert the spot that had  the image to play an embedded video as such:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DxkEe_l7S3g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I like not to refresh the page if possible.

Comment: Have you tried anything, if so show us what you've tried !

Comment: If you intend to code with jQuery, a half an hour spent browsing down the [list of methods](http://api.jquery.com/) (and selectors) is a good investment of your time given how much time it'll save you in future. (Then you'd know about the [`.replaceWith()` method](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).)

Comment: @nnnnnn +1 I've learned so many things about jQuery this way, things that I never knew existed. Of course, I forget them later since I don't need them, but still, it's great advice.

Comment: @nnnnnn +1 All things considered, that list isn't actually that long, so it's a great way to learn/refresh your memory.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: Here's a Fiddle to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/9pdX6/

It depends where you're getting the video id from.

Let's say you have this:

```
<img data-id="DxkEe_l7S3g" src="some_image" />
```

Then you could achieve what you're looking for like this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(
        '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + 
        $(this).data('id') + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
$('#yourImage').click(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<iframe>',{
        width: 560,
        height: 315,
        src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/DxkEe_l7S3g',
        frameborder: 0,
        allowfullscreen: true
    });
});
```

Or:

```
$('#yourImage').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<iframe>',{
        width: 560,
        height: 315,
        src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/DxkEe_l7S3g',
        frameborder: 0,
        allowfullscreen: true
    }).remove();
});
```

Or:

```
$('#yourImage').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().html('<iframe>',{
        width: 560,
        height: 315,
        src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/DxkEe_l7S3g',
        frameborder: 0,
        allowfullscreen: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function of jQuery. That allows you to take HTML and dump it into a container.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#yourImageID").click(change);
});

function change(){
    $("#imgParentDivID").html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DxkEe_l7S3g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. One of the easiest would probably be jQuery [.replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) Function that replace's the current element object with the new you imply.

Like so:

```
var vid = $("<iframe />", { frameborder: 0, src: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/DxkEe_l7S3g" }).css({ height: "315px", width: "560px" });

$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "img", function(e) {
        $(this).replaceWith(vid);
    });
})
```

## EXAMPLE

Another Option is to place the Iframe on the HTML, assign it's CSS to `display: none;` and use jQuery's [fadein](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)/[fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) to achieve a "classy" effect. Like so:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "img", function(e) {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow", function(e) { $("iframe").fadeIn("fast"); });
    });
})
```

## EXAMPLE

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, but thanks to jQuery's predefined javascript library, there are literally dozens if not 100's of way's to do what little you ask. These examples are but 2!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the image

```
<img src="..." data-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DxkEe_l7S3g"/>
```

with jQuery

```
$(document).on("click","img",function(){
    var frame = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'+$(this).data("src")+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $(this).replaceWith(frame);
});
```